# Disabling Microsoft Excel's auto formatting of dates

Tags: excel, vba

My situation goes as such:

I am importing data from a .CSV file, which contains a date column. For my own reasons (I have to process the data again later), I would like for the date column to remain as a String type variable until I conduct my own processing later.

So I import data from text under the DATA tab, select my delimiter and select the column data format to be TEXT. When the data is ported in, everything seems fine.

Now because the data is "unclean", the date field has a space in front and behind. So no problem: I write a macro to trim() the value, which goes as such:

```
Dim v As String
v = Cells(Row, col).Value
v = Trim(v)
Cells(Row, col).Value = v
```

With a loop to redefine row and col as per needed.

The problem is this: Once the macro runs, Excel recognizes the resultant String as a Date format, and therefore converts that cell's value to a Date formatted String. How can I leave it as a String value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim v As String
v = Cells(Row, col).Value
v = Trim(v)
Cells(Row, col).Value = "'" & v
```

If you prepend the cell value with a single quote, excel will treat it as a string.

You can also use:

```
Dim v As String
v = Cells(Row, col).Value
v = Trim(v)
Cells(Row, col).NumberFormat = "@"
Cells(Row, col).Value = v
```

Comment: I was just typing the second alternative. You're fast man. Also @wakka02 , Avoid using reserved keywords like `Row` as your variable names. Can cause havoc.

Comment: The NumberFormat option works beautifully! :) If I may ask, what does that mean tho?

@BranislavKollár, yeah I know, but this is literally the only method in the whole Excel sheet so I was a bit lazy to pick names. :P Thanks for the comment though!

Comment: @Wakka02 If you mean the `"@"` then that is a notation for "Text" format. You can check this in excel, click on cell, ctrl+1, choose text as number format and immediately change to custom. You will se the "@" in the "Type" field. To learn more you can see [MS Support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)